# Bash: Getting input from a manifest

Tags: bash

Is it possible too have a manifest file with directory strings, fx.

```
#css

SomeDIR/crap0.css
SomeDIR/crap1.css
SomeDIR/crap2.css

#js

SomeDIR/crap0.js
SomeDIR/crap1.js
SomeDIR/crap2.js
```

Lets call this file list.mf

then i have a bash code where i want too use the directory structure defined in list.mf

could be

```
cat %first entry in list.mf% > crap.txt
cat %second entr in list.mf% >> crap.txt
```

hoping for you're help, ask further questions if you don't understand my question :=)

/Mathias

Comment: Are you just looking for `grep -E -v '^#|^[ ]*$' list.mf >crap.txt` or do you actually want to do something with the contents of the manifest file?  `while read entry; do mkdir -p ${entry%/*}; done <list.mf` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done with a `for` loop or a simple find, e.g.:

```
for f in */*css ; do
    cat $f >> OUTPUT.file
done
# SAME
find Somedir/ -iname '*.css' -exec cat \{\} >> OUTPUT.file \;
```

But if you want to use a `config` (manifest) file, you can `source` it in your script, but that way you must use proper (`bash`) syntax in the config as well e.g. the file list should be in an array, etc, like this "`manifest.file`" file contents:

```
#css
export cssfiles=('SomeDIR/crap0.css' 'SomeDIR/crap1.css' 'SomeDIR/crap2.css')
#js
export jsfiles=('SomeDIR/crap0.js' 'SomeDIR/crap1.js' 'SomeDIR/crap2.js'
```

And in your script:

```
source /whatever/path/to/manifest.file
# ... then process those variables  
for elem in  ${cssfiles[*]} ; do
    cat $elem >> OUTPUTFILE
done
# and
for elem in  ${jsfiles[*]} ; do
    cat $elem >> ANOTHER_OUTPUTFILE
done
```

If you need that specific format for your `manifest` file you can still write some `awk`||`sed`||`grep` scripts to extract the proper lists.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for replying, but i need to use a manifest :=) the above solution is good but i need too be able to specify a order which it should be parsed on too the file :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file names really contain numbers, you can just

```
for i in {0..2} ; do
    grep crap$i'\.' list.mf >> crap.txt
done
```

If not, I'd use some more advanced language like Perl.